# TextInputLayout isn't using Theme Colors with dark background

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-theme, android-textinputlayout

I'm learning Android development and there's a problem i couldn't find the solution. I'm using a TextInputLayout that works fine with white or light backgrounds, applying the Theme accent color and so on. But, if i use it with a darker background (e.g. dark grey ), it doesn't use the theme colors.

[This image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eqoVA.jpg) shows the TextInputLayout applied with a dark background.

The question is: do i need to style the TextInputLayout directly or create additional statements for the theme?

(obs: i didn't change anything in the TextInputLayout XML yet)

I also tried solutions that i found here from 3/4 years ago, but it looks like deprecated.

Thanks.

Comment: No code, no help.

Comment: But looks like you may be overriding your styles incorrectly